# React component not able to get updated state value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Below is my component, I am trying to get updated value of attribute `text` from the state. But I am unable to get the updated value and I see only default value:

```
 class MainPage  extends Component {
  render () {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="MainStyle">
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <AdvancedEars />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
              <Clicker />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.whiteboard}>
           S: { this.state.text }
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

MainPage.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => (()=>
{
  console.log('I AM HERE');
  console.log(state);
  return {
    text: state.text
  }
});

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles),
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(MainPage);
```

Below is the component which changes the state. And I can see the value changed in the state in redux dev tools.

```
class Clicker  extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Button 
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      size="large"
      onClick={ this.props.saveData( "THIS IS ME" ) } >
          <Mic fontSize="large" />
      </Button>
  </Grid> 
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  text: state.transcription
});


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  saveData: text => dispatch(saveText( { text } ))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Clicker);
```

When the button is clicked I should be able to see the value as `THIS IS ME` but I am unable to get the value, it is blank all the time. Here is the reducer:

```
const defaultState = {
  text: ""
};

const transcribeReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.TEXT_SAVE: {

      let { text } = action.payload;
      let newState = {
          ...state,
          text,
      }
      return newState;
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default transcribeReducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

`mapStateToProps` needs to be a function that maps redux state to the props passed down to your component.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   text: state.text
});
```

In your code `mapStateToProps` is a function that returns another function that returns the state:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => (()=>
{
  console.log('I AM HERE');
  console.log(state);
  return {
    text: state.text
  }
});
```

Comment: Also, inside `MainPage`, you are accessing `this.state.text`, I guess what you are looking for is `this.props.text`

Comment: Yes it is `this.props.text` , but still I am unable to access the state value. In the function where I have a console output `I AM HERE` I can se the state with the property `text` but it is empty.

Comment: your `mapStateToProps` is also wrong, did you fix it ?

Comment: I found the issue. It was because I was using the state object directly in reducer, when I cloned it and then used it it started working.